# Joining two tables with mapping from user constraints

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join two tables based on some constraints provided by the user. I'm not sure how to put this in words, so I will explain what I am trying to do using an example:

I have two tables:

```
l_id    |    l_fileid                           c_id    |    c_fileid
---------------------                           ---------------------
1       |       X1                                1     |       X2
2       |       X1                                3     |       X2
3       |       X1                                2     |       Y2
4       |       X1                                
5       |       Y1                                
2       |       Y1
```

The user provides a mapping like `X1 -> X2, Y1 -> Y2`  and for this the result would look like this:

```
l_id    |    l_fileid    |    c_fileid
-------------------------------------
1     |       X1       |       X2
2     |       X1       |       NULL
3     |       X1       |       X2
4     |       X1       |       NULL
5     |       Y1       |       NULL
2     |       Y1       |       Y2
```

I have managed to write down a query that could do this, but I'm hoping that this is **not the best way**. Here's what I have come up with so far:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT * FROM L WHERE l_fileid='X1')
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM C WHERE c_fileid='X2')
    ON l_id=c_id
)
UNION 
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT * FROM L WHERE l_fileid='Y1')
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM C WHERE c_fileid='Y2')
    ON l_id=c_id
)
```

Comment: Are you sure your sample output is right? What's "Y" on the last line? Where is the id column coming from?

Comment: why for example `1, X1, X2`and `2, X1, null` ?

Comment: Sorry, updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: newest edit to the question looks good. Amended answer to match.

Try this:

```
select l_id, l_fileid, c_fileid from l left outer join c on 
   l_id=c_id and 
     ((l_fileid='x1' and c_fileid='x2') or 
      (l_fileid='y1' and c_fileid='y2'))
```

Which produces:

```
+ --------- + ------------- + ------------- +
| l_id      | l_fileid      | c_fileid      |
+ --------- + ------------- + ------------- +
| 1         | x1            | x2            |
| 2         | x1            |               |
| 3         | x1            | x2            |
| 4         | x1            |               |
| 5         | y1            |               |
| 2         | y1            | y2            |
+ --------- + ------------- + ------------- +
```

My full script is here, if that helps anyone else come up with answers:

```
create table l (
    l_id  int,
    l_fileid varchar(10)
);

create table c (
    c_id  int,
    c_fileid varchar(10)
);

insert into l (l_id, l_fileid) values (1, 'x1');
insert into l (l_id, l_fileid) values (2, 'x1');
insert into l (l_id, l_fileid) values (3, 'x1');
insert into l (l_id, l_fileid) values (4, 'x1');
insert into l (l_id, l_fileid) values (5, 'y1');
insert into l (l_id, l_fileid) values (2, 'y1');

insert into c (c_id, c_fileid) values (1, 'x2');
insert into c (c_id, c_fileid) values (3, 'x2');
insert into c (c_id, c_fileid) values (2, 'y2');

 select l_id, l_fileid, c_fileid from l left outer join c on 
   l_id=c_id and 
     ((l_fileid='x1' and c_fileid='x2') or 
      (l_fileid='y1' and c_fileid='y2'))
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was trying since a long time but couldn't get the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like that should work.

```
SELECT * FROM l
LEFT JOIN c ON l_id=c_id AND l_fileid='X1' AND c_fileid='X2'
UNION
SELECT * FROM l
LEFT JOIN c ON l_id=c_id AND l_fileid='Y1' AND c_fileid='Y2'
```